# Is there anything like PPI or Perl::Critic for C?

Tags: c, perl, parsing, tokenize, perl-critic

[PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.206/lib/PPI.pm) and [Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/~elliotjs/Perl-Critic-1.105/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) allow programmers to detect certain things in the syntax of their Perl programs.

Is there anything like it that will tokenize/parse C and give you a chance to write a script to do something with that information?

Answer (score 17):

C related programs:

- [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST_model_checker) (Berkeley Lazy Abstraction
  Software verification Tool) — a
  software model checker for C programs
  based on lazy abstraction.
- [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) — A compiler that includes
  a static analyzer.
- [Frama-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frama-C) — A static analysis
  framework for C.
- [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse) — A tool designed to find
  faults in the Linux kernel.
- [Splint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_(programming_tool)) — An open source evolved
  version of Lint (C language).

[List of tools for Static Code Analysis for C (more than the list above)](http://spinroot.com/static/)

Answer (score 13):

There is an open source program called [Splint](http://splint.org/):

> Splint is a tool for statically checking C programs for security vulnerabilities and coding mistakes. With minimal effort, Splint can be used as a better lint. If additional effort is invested adding annotations to programs, Splint can perform stronger checking than can be done by any standard lint.

Answer (score 11):

If I remember correctly, that's what [lint](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3567/lint.html) does.

Comment: Lint looks at more than just syntax, it also looks for fishy constructs like using a variable before setting them.

Answer (score 5):

It's a little off topic, but on the subject of valuable code analyzers for C is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to catch dodgy memory management.